How can broadcast a custom notification on specefic channel? (Filament, Laravel, Notification, Php)
I'm trying to make a notification that scopes Pusher channel to a specific tenant, because I have multitenants on my project (admin, tenant), and also I have multi-envs (local, staging for testing on a server, and prod). My main goal with this is to get a kind of way to make a Filament notification overwriting 'broadcast' method, with this, being capable to make notifications on local in the admin panel, and only see these notifications on local and in the admin panel.
Right now, if I try to do a broadcast notification in that same way, I will see the same notification on local, and staging (prod no bc don't have the notification).
This is what I'm trying to do (It's not working):
1 - First, I have defined the channel:
Broadcast::channel('Notifications.App.Models.User.{id}.{currentPanel}.{tenantSimpleId}', function ($user) {
    return Auth::check();
});

Being currentPanel 'admin', 'tenant' or 'participant'. It will be depending on the result of the next TenantHelper's function:

public static function getCurrentPanel(): ?string
{
    if (!self::isCentralDomain()) {
        return 'tenant';
    } elseif (self::isAdminDomain()) {
        return 'admin';
    } elseif (self::isParticipantDomain()) {
        return 'participant';
    }
    return null;
}

2 - I'm extending from Filament's notification the next class:
use App\Events\UserBroadcastNotification;
use Filament\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class UserScopedNotification extends Notification
{
    protected string $channelName;

    public function broadcast(Model | Authenticatable | Collection | array $users, ?string $channel = null): static
    {
        if (! is_iterable($users)) {
            $users = [$users];
        }
    
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $currentPanel = $channel;
            $tenantSimpleId = tenant() ? '.' . tenant()->simple_id : '';
            $this->channelName = "Notifications.App.Models.User.{$user->getKey()}.{$currentPanel}{$tenantSimpleId}";
            $broadcastNotification = $this->toBroadcast();
            $user->notify($broadcastNotification);
        }
    
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function toBroadcast(): UserBroadcastNotification
    {
        $data = $this->toArray();
        $data['format'] = 'filament';
        return new UserBroadcastNotification($data, $this->channelName);
    }
}

With this, I'm trying to do the same static notification to call different methods on the same instance. Like this:
php
UserScopedNotification::make()
    ->color('success')
    ->icon('heroicon-o-check-circle')
    ->title('PDF generated successfully')
    ->broadcast(auth()->user(), TenantHelper::getCurrentPanel()); // Getting the user and current panel (admin, tenant, participant....)

3- Then, I have defined the broadcast event with the same channel:
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Filament\Notifications\BroadcastNotification;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class UserBroadcastNotification extends BroadcastNotification implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(public array $data, public string $channelName)
    {
        parent::__construct($data);
    }
    
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [new PrivateChannel($this->channelName)];
    }
}

4- Finally, I'm trying to listen to this event on a custom Livewire component extending from Filament's notification component:
use App\Helpers\TenantHelper;
use Filament\Notifications\Livewire\Notifications;

class LivewireBroadcastNotification extends Notifications
{
    /**
     * Get the broadcast channel for the authenticated user.
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getBroadcastChannel(): ?string
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        if (! $user) {
            return null;
        }
    
        if (method_exists($user, 'receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn')) {
            return $user->receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn();
        }
        $userId = auth()->user()->getKey();
        $currentPanel = TenantHelper::getCurrentPanel();
        $tenantSimpleId = tenant() ? '.' . tenant()->simple_id : '';
        return "Notifications.App.Models.User.{$userId}.{$currentPanel}{$tenantSimpleId}";
    }
}

and I put this Livewire like this on admin panel:
public function boot(): void {
    $this->app->bind(Notification::class, UserScopedNotification::class);
}

$panel
    ->databaseNotifications()
    ->renderHook(
        PanelsRenderHook::BODY_END,
        fn(): string => Blade::render('@livewire('livewire-broadcast-notification')'),
    )

I have tried all that I have mentioned.
